# Azure SQL Database traffic migration to newer Gateways

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Got an email from azure regarding Azure SQL Database traffic migration to newer Gateways. There are several links in the email including [Azure SQL Database traffic migration to newer Gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-gateway-migration)
Having read the article it says:

You will not be impacted if you have

- Redirection as the connection policy
- Connections to SQL Database from inside Azure and using Service Tags
- Connections made using supported versions of JDBC Driver for SQL Server will see no impact.

New to azure. Can anyone offer any advice on the following:

1. I'm trying to find out where the connection policys are listed in azure so I can see if its redirect, proxy or default? I have an MVC5 website connected to azure SQL database.
2. Connection string for website is in the web.config and have no idea if using service tags? I have checked my connection strings in azure and its ADO.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received the same email. I have received similar emails in the past. The only thing I do is add the IPs of the new gateways on the firewall rules on the Azure SQL Database logical server as shown on the image below.

[image]

You do not have to do anything else. Based on my experience everything keeps working as usual.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added in the IP address under my SQL Server name.