# Azure SQL Database traffic migration to newer Gateways when using Webapp-->Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

I have received an email from Microsoft regarding "Azure SQL Database traffic migration to newer Gateways". These changes are highlighted on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/gateway-migration?tabs=in-progress-ip).

In that page it says that you will not be impacted if you have:

- Redirection as the connection policy
- Connections to SQL Database from inside Azure and using Service Tags
- Connections made using supported versions of JDBC Driver for SQL Server will see no impact. For supported JDBC versions, see Download Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server.

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303522/azure-sql-database-traffic-migration-to-newer-gateways) similar question on Stackoverflow but my situation is different.

I have a simple scenario of a webapp and an SQL database where I access my database from the webapp using the connection string. The connection string looks like this:

```sh
Data Source=tcp:myspecialdb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=my-prod-db;User Id=johndoe@myspecialdb.database.windows.net;Password=mysecretpassword;
```

Can someone please tell me if I will be impacted? Thank you.

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: @LeonYue, the change will happen mid Sept.

Comment: Hi @Stackedup, we can't answer you certainly because it is not happened, I also receive the email from Microsoft. As I understand, If you web app host in Azure and Azure SQL database allow Azure Service or resources access this server,  I think it won't be impacted. It more affect IP address firewall settings.

Comment: Thanks @LeonYue. It looks like that if I use the service tags then it won't be a problem. I believe that's how I have set up my configuration. Like in my connection string above, my service tag is my-prod-db/myspecialdb. so fingers corssed it should go without any problems.

Comment: yeah, that's right. If we met any error, Azure also will provide the solution/guides for us. Can I post it as answer?

Comment: @LeonYue, I will mark this as an answer on 16th or 17th of Sept depending how much I pull my hair out. :)

Comment: haha, you are so humorous! How about mark it first for your hair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't answer you certainly because it is not happened, I also received the email from Microsoft.

[image]

[image]

As I understand, If you web app host in Azure and Azure SQL database allow Azure Service or resources access this server, I think it won't be impacted. It more affect IP address firewall settings.

And as you said: It looks like that if I use the service tags then it won't be a problem. I believe that's how I have set up my configuration. Like in my connection string above, my service tag is my-prod-db/myspecialdb. so fingers corssed it should go without any problems.

If we have questions, get answers from community experts in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/index.html). If you have a support plan and you need technical help, please [contact us](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview).